# Folder copy VC++

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, visual-c++, msdn

i want to copy a directory from one drive to another drive.
My selected directory contain many sub directories and files.
How can i implement the same using vc++

Comment: I'd recommend boost (nabulke's reply) if you need a portable solution, or SHFileOperation (nobugz' reply) for best platform integration - it gives you basically the same "copy" as explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [SHFileOperation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28VS.85%29.aspx) API function is the workhorse function for copying files.  It supports recursing directories.  Review the options available in the [SHFILEOPSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759795%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure to control the copy.

Comment: SHFileOperation is officially deprecated on Windows Vista+ and its delete feature unofficially "just doesn't work" on Vista+.

Comment: It is *not* deprecated.  Vista merely has another mousetrap to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The hard way. copy every file individually.

Use `FindFirst()` and `FindNext()` to iterate over the content of a directory
Use `SetCurrentDirectory()` to go in and out of directories
Use `CreateDirectory()` to create the new folders tree
and finally, use `CopyFile()` to copy the actual files

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the boost library this is your friend:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Check the tutorial for nice examples using a filesystem iterator.

To get you started:

```
#include <iostream>
#include “boost/filesystem.hpp”
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
  boost::filesystem::path path1("/usr/local/include"); // your source path
  boost::filesystem::path::iterator pathI = path1.begin();
  while (pathI != path1.end())
    {
    std::cout << *pathI << std::endl; // here you could copy the file or create a directory
    ++pathI;
    }
  return 0;
  }
```