# How do I copy a file Or folder in the Program Files folder

Tags: c++

How do I copy a file Or folder in the Program Files folder.

Experimented with:

```
 system("xcopy pro_s\\pro C:\\Program Files  /e /i /h");
```

But I did not succeed.

Comment: Run your program with administrator rights

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
system("xcopy \"C:\\Program Files\\foldertocopy\" \"C:\\destination\" /e /i /h"); // Copy from

system("xcopy \"C:\\source\" \"C:\\Program Files\\foldertocopyinto\" /e /i /h"); // Copy to
```

The latter will need admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in "Program Files" which can cause issues. Try surrounding it with double quotes `\"C:\\Program Files\"` or try with `"C:\\Progra~1"`

If you are on C++, you can use mighty boost as well:
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2536438 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/8594696
or
on windows see [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28VS.85%29.aspx) API